# How to get all udp ports list on system with c#

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, udp, port

I want to get all ports list from my computer that they are in use by c#.

For doing this I tried this code :

```
IPEndPoint[] list_all_ports = System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().GetActiveUdpListeners();
```

But its not show all ports list , and some of them are missing.

For example when i use `cmd` `netstat` command like this :

```
netstat -an | find "UDP"
```

It gives me all the `UDP` ports list that they are in use by my computer.
But in c# , The list is incomplete.

for more explanation please see the image :
[image]

what I want is to get this kind of `UDP` ports list by c#.

How can I do that ?

Comment: Which are missing? In the screenshot, what is the significance of the red marked items and the red arrow?

Comment: @NetMage yes exactly

Comment: That didn't answer any of my questions.

Comment: @NetMage i mean yes the red marked items are missed in c#. and i wonder this code is work with another projects code but in my current project it shows list incomplete !

Comment: Those are IPv6 ports - do the following IPv6 ports show up?

Comment: When I run the same command on Windows 10, I get the IPv6Any ports as well - are you a local administrator?

Comment: @NetMage really i don't know why this problem happened !!! but I decide to change my project and rewrite scripts and now  my problem is gone !!! but Interestingly in previous project problem still there !!!   by the way thanks for your response